# Unable to install scanner driver

Tags: scanner

I am using ubuntu 17.04.
I am unable to install driver for panasonic kx mb1900 as  I am unable to edit 40-libsane.rules. I don't have 40-libsane.rules but I have 40-libsane.rules.save  which i am unable to edit. I used sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules. But all i got is a blank text editor window.
Kindly help

Comment: you need root permission, use `sudo`

Comment: I used sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules. But all i got is a blank text

Comment: so it is blank, edit as you need to

Comment: if you are still out there Lijin George, surely it is 60-libsane.rules that you want to edit; what is the `lsusb` of your device please; SANE http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-PANASONIC does not offer much support for panasonic devices; I suspect  you need `gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules`

Comment: I see https://panasonic.cn/support/download/manual/files/201407/linux/ScannerDriver_Ubuntu_ENG_007.pdf that Panasonic make a scanner driver panamfs-scan-1.2.0-x86_64.tar.gz for 64bit systems; have you also seen that?